# How does Arcane Strike scale with multiclassing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, multi-classing

[Arcane Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/arcane-strike-combat/) provides a damage boost based on Caster Level. For characters that remain in their original spellcasting class, this is simple enough. But what if you multiclass Bard/Sorcerer?

- Would it take your total spellcasting level or highest?
- What about Bard/Druid (where you're still gaining spellcasting levels but now some are Divine)?
- Finally, what about Bard/Rogue with bonus(es) to Caster Level such as [Ioun Stone (orange prism)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone/) or the [Magical Knack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-knack/) trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any caster level you like, but there is no rule about combining any separate caster levels, so you would pick the highest one. Bonuses to caster level, like an ioun stone, would count for this purpose. And a bard/druid *can* use the druid caster level (the requirement that you can cast arcane spells does not implicitly mean that you have to use the caster level of an arcane-spellcasting class; that would have to be spelled out in the feat’s benefit and it isn’t).

Comment: There is a [FAQ request](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uqeh?Arcane-Strike-with-a-divine-caster-level#1) open to clarify the benefit with divine caster levels.

Comment: Actually, reading the feat...it says 'for every five caster levels you possess'...it doesn't say 'in one class', so...if I have 5 levels in bard and 5 in druid, don't I possess 10 caster levels, despite my highest caster level being 5?

Comment: @YogoZuno I suppose that is a valid argument. I don’t personally buy it, since the rules often implicitly assume a single class and stacking is generally the exception, not the norm, so I would expect an explicit mention of stacking if it were meant to happen, but I can see the argument. And I would personally be happy to rule that way, anyway, just because multiclassed spellcasters have enough problems as it is, and Arcane Strike is such a poor feat.